# How to handle special characters in python requests post request

Tags: python, http, python-requests, request, http-post

I'm trying to send an HTTP POST request using the python `requests` package.

The working curl command looks like the following (captured from chrome dev tools network tab, right clicked on someFile.php, and chose "copy as cURL"). When run in a terminal, it outputs a valid, nonempty, response.

```
curl 'https://somedomain.com/someFile.php' \
  --data-raw $'abc=ZXC%20*%20QWE%20***%20BNM%20((someThing%20%3D%200))%20AND%20anotherThing%20%3E%3D%20\'2020-5-9\'%20IOP%20&someparam=1&myhash=a5d96895cab824fbd9bb85627a8f909d'
```

I attempted to replicate the POST request in python with:

```
import requests
url = 'https://somedomain.com/someFile.php'
out = requests.post(url,data=r'abc=ZXC%20*%20QWE%20***%20BNM%20((someThing%20%3D%200))%20AND%20anotherThing%20%3E%3D%20\'2020-5-9\'%20IOP%20&someparam=1&myhash=a5d96895cab824fbd9bb85627a8f909d')
print(out.text)
```

... but this just prints an empty string.

How do I handle this curl command in python?

Comment: Have you tried using `urllib.parse.unquote(data)` and also changing `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Thanks! Setting `headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}` was successful! I had thought this was the default. And I don't send this in `curl`. But it seems required when using urllib. I didn't use `urllib.parse.unquote(data)` (since the data is url encoded)

Comment: Then I believe, I can post this as answer, right?

Comment: Yes - that's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply setting `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should solve your problem.

```py
headers={}
headers["Content-Type"]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
data="....."
output=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
```

Comment: This worked. It seems like `curl` defaults to adding the `Content-Type` header, while `requests` doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
url="https://somedomain.com/someFile.php"
params = {"abc":"text without quote symbols", "someParam":.... }
res=requests.post(url, params=params)
print(res.text)
```

Comment: Could you show how this would look for the given request body? Eg - how do you deal with the ' characters, like in `20\'2020-5-9\'%20`?

Comment: I've tried the following. I also tried replacing `'` with `\'`. I also tried replacing `'` with nothing. None of these methods work. I tried your example with `params` as follows, but it doesn't work: `params = {"abc":"ZXC%20*%20QWE%20***%20BNM%20((someThing%20%3D%200))%20AND%20anotherThing%20%3E%3D%20'2020-5-9'%20IOP%20", 'someparam':'1', 'myhash':'a5d96895cab824fbd9bb85627a8f909d'}`