# POST request list python-requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests, format

I am trying to **POST** `Boxes = [{'X': 2423, 'Y': 532, 'W': 7456, 'H': 2345}]` to the DRF server, I receive status code 200, However, on the server, I receive weird format: `"Boxes": "[{\"X\": 1028, \"Y\": 228, \"W\": 711, \"H\": 852}]"`.

I don't understand where the '/' comes from.

Here is the **POST** request in python:

```
                Boxes = [{"X": 2423, "Y": 532, "W": 7456, "H": 2345}]

                
                url = "http://art1x.pythonanywhere.com/snippets/1/"
                username = ""
                password = ""
                data = {"Boxes": json.dumps(Boxes)}
                response = requests.put(url, auth=(username, password), data=data)
                print(response.status_code)
```

'Boxes' is a list

Please help! Any suggestion is valuable

Answer (score 0):

The weird format looks like escape characters. Setting content type should fix this i think.

e.g:

```
headers["Content-Type"]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

[link to post explaining Content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696683/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-python-requests-post-request)

Comment: its still like:     "Boxes": "[{\"X\": 926, \"Y\": 125, \"W\": 300, \"H\": 383}]",

Answer (score 0):

Remove `json.dumps` if you want to send Boxes as json object instead of a string:

```
data = {"Boxes": Boxes}
```

`json.dumps(Boxes)` convert Boxes into a string. `requests.put` then convert data into string for transport, where it inserts escape characters because the content is a string.

Comment: the response looks like this:     "Boxes": "H",

Comment: Without API spec, I don't know what the server expects.

Comment: The server expects a TextField with length 10000